# Pass touch to another view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` as a subview in another `UIScrollView` I am trying to prevent scrolling from occurring in the subview and pass the touch to the superview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.outerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.outerScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    self.gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    self.gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.tableViewController.tableView addGestureRecognizer:self.gestureRecognizer];
    [self.outerScrollView addSubview:self.tableViewController.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.outerScrollView];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{


    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (gesture.view == self.tableViewController.tableView) {
            self.tableViewController.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            // Pass to self.outerScrollView
            // Trying to make self.outerScrollView take over the touch 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just disable scrolling in the subview?

Comment: hey I could do that, but I would like the scrollview to eventually start scrolling when the outerscrollview reaches a particular contentOffset Point.

Comment: what about giving your inner view a reference to the outerview. then set scrolling enabled once it hits that point

Comment: what i decided to do is to manage the contentOffset for the outerscrollview manually in handlePanGesture:

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Comment: I feel its hackish...would be nice to figure out how to pass the touch to the superview

Comment: could you just call that method on the subview then? `[self.subview handlePanGesture:gesture];`